# Retaining original image size

Tags: images

Since I have a website for **Comic reading**, if I use reduced image sizes, it will also reduce the text which will be difficult to read. I want to retain the image size. No problem even if it creates a scrolling window. The post width should adjust to the image.

Anything that will work? I have tried setting 0,0 values in **Settings -> Media**.

Comment: Can you please provide more info ? Like which theme/plugin etc you are using ? Paste the code responsible for spitting out the output image.

Comment: http://myreadingmanga.info/wordpress/?p=1578 Check the link. The image is actually 1800px wide. But it is resized to post width. We are using Genesis theme

Answer (score 0):

**Paste this code in the style.css file of you current active theme. (file path: /wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/style.css )**

```
.entry-content img.size-full {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Subha, I already tried that, but can I extend the post width along with that? It will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop instead of

```
   <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
```

you can get your original sized images as below:

```
while(have_posts()):the_post();
$orignalimage= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full');
$imageurl=$orignalimage[0];
//now to show the image you can use the html <img> tag
echo '<img src="'.$imageurl.'"/>
//you can also give the height width and other parameters.
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your CSS, just remove `max_width` on the `.site-inner, .wrap` line ( `.site-inner,.wrap{margin:0 auto;max-width:1140px;}`) and the theme will adapt to big-size screens.

Otherwise, remove `img` selector from `embed, iframe, img, object, video, .wp-caption {
    max-width: 100%; }` ( to  `embed, iframe, object, video, .wp-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
} )` and the image will be displayed with the size indicated inline in the `width` attribute of the `img` tag.

Comment: Simon, I have solved the image size part, but the post seems not extending along with the image.